# Couldn't compile gcc-code-assist gcc-code-assist-0.1-4.4.4, crti.o not found

Tags: debian, emacs

I would like to improve Emacs23 on Debian Wheezy adding some modules to code competion. I decided to install GCCSense which requires gcc-code-assist. With compiling the latter I've a problem. `Make` says that crti.o couldn't be found. I have it in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu, but ld can't cope with it. It seems to be looking for it in another directory... How to solve that problem?

`/usr/bin/ld: cannot find crti.o: No such file or directory`

Comment: Can't you add it to your path?

Comment: I knew that I should do it, but I tried to set wrong variable (LD_LIBRARY_PATH instead of LIBRARY_PATH). Now I know that the proper variable is LIBRARY_PATH. I exported it and the compilation is being continued Thank you, it's solved!

Comment: Please put that in an answer, and accept it, so that the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've the desired answer for you! You have to export LIBRARY_PATH in your shell. Then the installation should be continued!

`export LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/`

Good luck!